# Blank depth buffer from ARSCNView in DRAW_QUAD pass of SCNTechnique

Tags: ios, arkit, metal, depth-buffer, scntechnique

I'm trying to do depth-testing in a post-processing step of an AR SceneKit demo. I would need the depth map of the rendere ARSCNView for that. It seems impossible to get it using an SCNTechnique.

I keep getting blank (full of 1.0-s) depth buffers when trying to use the depth from a DRAW_SCENE pass as input in a DRAW_QUAD pass in an SCNTechnique. 
I've followed the guides at [SCNTechnique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique) and named the depth target. 
Is this a bug in the implementation of SCNTechnique, or am I missing something in the configuration?

The color buffer is chained correctly, and the example from https://github.com/lachlanhurst/SCNTechniqueTest/tree/pixelate works.

Here's the debug view of the metal technique, as you can see, the depth buffer is completely white.
[image: Metal shader debug view]

Here's the technique plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pixelate_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>color_scene</string>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>depth_scene</string>
            </dict>
            <key>colorStates</key>
            <dict>
                <key>clear</key>
                <true/>
                <key>clearColor</key>
                <string>sceneBackground</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>resample_pixelation</key>
        <dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_QUAD</string>
            <key>program</key>
            <string>doesntexist</string>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>pixelate_pass_through_vertex</string>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string>pixelate_pass_through_fragment</string>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>colorSampler</key>
                <string>color_scene</string>
                <key>depthSampler</key>
                <string>depth_scene</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>pixelate_scene</string>
        <string>resample_pixelation</string>
    </array>
    <key>targets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>color_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>color</string>
        </dict>
        <key>depth_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>depth</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>symbols</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The shaders look like this:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <metal_geometric>
using namespace metal;


#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct custom_vertex_t
{
    float4 position [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)]];
};

constexpr sampler s = sampler(coord::normalized,
                              address::repeat,
                              filter::nearest);

struct out_vertex_t
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 uv;
};

vertex out_vertex_t pixelate_pass_through_vertex(custom_vertex_t in [[stage_in]], constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]])
{
    out_vertex_t out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.uv = float2((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);
    return out;
};



fragment half4 pixelate_pass_through_fragment(out_vertex_t vert [[stage_in]], texture2d<float, access::sample> colorSampler [[texture(0)]], texture2d<float, access::sample> depthSampler [[texture(1)]])
{
    float4 fragment_color = colorSampler.sample( s, vert.uv);
    float ar_depth = depthSampler.sample(s, vert.uv).r;

    return half4(fragment_color * 0.5 + float4(ar_depth) * 0.5);
};
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get the depth buffer of an ARSCNView frame in the SCNTechnique shaders?

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment shader the type for the `depthSampler` should be `depth2d` instead of `texture2d`. Setting up the pipeline correctly using `SCNTechnique` can be somewhat tricky, but it works once all the peaces of the puzzle are right.